# Why did "it" lose its initial 'h' but other pronouns such as "him" and "her" didn't?

Tags: pronunciation, pronouns, historical-change, old-english, middle-english

The pronouns *it, him, her* had an initial *h* in the older forms of English which has been retained in *her, him*, but **lost** in *it* (formerly ***h**it*).

Etymology of *it* ([Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/it)):

> From Middle English *it, hit* ( > dialectal English *hit* (“it”)), from Old English *hit* (“it”), from Proto-Germanic **hit*

The word *it* had an initial *h* in both spelling & pronunciation but was then lost in Middle English onwards. Other pronouns such as *him, her* had also an initial *h* in Middle & Old English but has been retained.

Was this an irregular change or is there any explanation for the loss of initial *h* in that particular word?

Comment: The full OED says *The early attestation and eventual prevalence of loss of initial **h-** is **due to low stress**; similar forms are found for other pronouns of the third person, as **'em**.*

Comment: *She* has also had an initial <h>, if in fact it was a regular change (conceivably palatalized before a high vowel, former *hio* if I remember correctly). But! It is otherwise idiosyncratic to say that *she* had an <h> if for a correct formalism we have to consider them separate words, whether related or not. So, what you mean is that *the pronouns* hit, him, here, *etc. have an initial h*, clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the following source, the h was lost because of its unemphasized position:

> The ***[h-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/it)*** was lost due to being in an unemphasized position, as in modern speech the h- in "give it to him," "ask her," is heard only "in the careful speech of the partially educated" [Weekley, Ernest, An Etymological Dictionary of Modern English]

(Etymonline)

Comment: "in the careful speech of the partially educated" - I like that!

Comment: I guess related to this, "him" and "her" commonly occur at the start of sentences/as subjects of verbs and will get more emphasis, while "it" starts sentences less often and occurs later in the sentence (except in forms like "it is raining" where as a purely conventional word it's unlikely to be stressed).

Comment: You have a typo "unenphasized" --> "unemphasized"